# Paraview: Convert an ASCII file to binary format to save space

Tags: binary, ascii, vtk, paraview

I have a .vtk file (0.25 TB)  n ASCII format which I visualize in ParaView. I like to transfer the data to my collaborators for which I would like to convert it into a binary format.

I tried to search through the internet and was unsuccessful in obtaining a solution.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Thanks,
Prithivi

Answer (score 4):

You can open your .vtk file in ParaView and then save it in binary format but it won't compress it for you:

- File -> Save Data -> Choose `Legacy VTK Files (.vtk)` format -> Change ASCII to Binary.

But, you could be more detailed here:

- If your data is a VTK unstructured grid: File -> Save Data -> Choose `VTK UnstructuredGrid Files (.vtu)` -> Data Mode to `Appended` -> Compressor Type to `LZMA` -> Compression Level to `9` to get smallest file
- If your data is a VTK structured grid: File -> Save Data -> Choose `VTK StructuredGrid Files (.vts)` -> Data Mode to `Appended` -> Compressor Type to `LZMA` -> Compression Level to `9` to get smallest file
- If your data is a VTK polydata: File -> Save Data -> Choose `VTK PolyData Files (.vtp)` -> Data Mode to `Appended` -> Compressor Type to `LZMA` -> Compression Level to `9` to get smallest file

Answer (score 2):

My file is quite huge so can;t be opened via Paraview. To do it using the script, I found the following piece of python code to be useful.

```
from paraview.simple import *
r = LegacyVTKReader( FileNames=['Yourfilename.vtk'] )
SaveData('Yourfilename_binary.vtk', proxy=r)
```

Comment: The function `SaveData()` is not working with Paraview's older versions (like 3.98.1). I found its implementation [here](https://kitware.github.io/paraview-docs/latest/python/_modules/paraview/simple.html) and moved it to my code. How can I save my file as ASCII? Calling it like `SaveData(filename, proxy=px, FileType='Ascii')` is not working.